# Research topics in representation theory of algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, soft-question, quivers

I was wondering what are some of the hot topics in quiver representation or representation theory of algebras that can lead to good mathematics and is important to many mathematicians and top mathematicians?

I'm not looking for exact question or anything but more like an overview/idea of some topics. For e.g.- quiver varieties, tau-tilting theory, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid this is really too broad for a helpful answer; have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representation_theory_topics

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I don't think that list is very helpful for outlining possible directions for research topics. It is mostly a list of standard textbook topics, which are very different from the directions in which research is moving.

Comment: It's 15 years old at this point, but maybe this book is interesting to you?: "Trends in Representation Theory of Algebras and Related Topics," https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-406

Answer (score 3):

One of the best way to learn what is hot is to attend conferences and be in touch with people in the field.
The new homepage https://fdlist.math.uni-bielefeld.de/t/welcome-to-fdlist/21 contains a lot of information including a list of all related conferences.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point is the MSC2020 database. The codes 16G20 and 16G70 are directly related to quivers. Now you can look up recent papers on MathSciNet or zbMATH (subscription required).

Comment: Subscription is required for MathSciNet, but not for zbMath.